# Using IMFSourceReader to open a video file

Tags: video, windows-runtime, c++-cx, ms-media-foundation

I want to open a video file using `IMFSourceReader` to access its Frames as IMFSample.
In a WinRT C++ Class I send the `RandomAccessStream` of a video file and use the following code to create an `IMFSourceReader` object.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

ComPtr<IMFSourceReader> pSourceReader;
ComPtr<IMFByteStream> spByteStream;

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Initialize the Media Foundation platform.
    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);


    hr = MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx((IUnknown*)InputVideoStream, &spByteStream);

    ComPtr<IMFAttributes> Atrr;
    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&Atrr, 10);
    hr = Atrr->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, true);

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream(spByteStream.Get(), Atrr.Get(), &pSourceReader);
 }
```

But the HRESULT of the function MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream() is returning `The Byte Stream  Type of the Given URL is unsupported`.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Can anyone show me the correct way? I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: The return code sounds pretty clear. What is the video/audio format of the file you want to play? If you are unable to play it back with TopoEdit either, then you have no available codec for this format.

Comment: I can open some MP4 files (codec ID isom) but not every MP4 files (for example codec ID mp42). Is there any other way to extract the video frames other than using IMFSourceReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to the `The Byte Stream Type of the Given URL is unsupported` problem of `IMFSourceReader`. I could read Byte Stream of `WMV` files, some `MP4` files but not all kind of video files. So before using `MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream()` I converted the video stream to `VC-1/WMV` format which the `MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream()` is able to read. I used the [Transcoding media sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-transcode-sample-f7ba5269) of MSDN to convert he video into WMV video. Now I am able to use `MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream()` without any error.

Answer (score 1):

The return code sounds pretty clear. What is the video/audio format of the file you want to play? If you are unable to play it back with TopoEdit either, then you have no available codec for this format.

> Is there any other way to extract the video frames other than using
>   IMFSourceReader?

To extract an uncompressed video sample no matter what way, first you have to decode it from it's encoded stream. In your case you are missing a decoder. Maybe your question should be *is there another framework I can use instead of Media Foundation*?

I don't think so. The DirectShow API is not available for Windows RT, as far as I know even ffmpeg **can not** be compiled for that OS. So I guess your only choice is to rely on Media Foundation and it's set of codecs.

My only idea coming to mind is to find third party decoder components (MFTs) or build your own decoders.

**Edit:**

In your case the IMFMSourceReader factory function (MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx) is unable to create source reader. This will mean that your system lacks a adequate container parser (i.e. splitter a.k.a. demultiplexor). So it is unable to extract the elementary media streams from the container. This is really the stage before decoding.

So again, you can search for a third-party media source parser, or write/port one. Of course you will first find out what is the particular format that MF is lacking source reader for.

Some links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee318417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I am a bit confused here as I am new to this. As far as I know about MFT it has a ProcessInput() where an IMFSample is passed and ProcessOutput() returns decoded IMFSample. So at first I need to extract IMFSample from video using IMFSourceReader->ReadSample() before I can use the MFT. But SourceReader fails to load the video in the first place. Hence there needs to be a way to open video with source reader using an MFT decoder at the same time. Can you direct me to any tutorial or link on this?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I don't know of good MF tutorials, and I'll be also interested anyone to post some. You can check the materials on MSDN, also MF's blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mf/ . Also you can check out this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnode/

Comment: I can play the video files with TopoEdit. It shows in the diagram that it uses 'Microsoft H264 Video Decoder MFT'. So does it mean that I have the necessary codecs already installed for this format? And If I can somehow invoke this decoder MFT, will I be able to use IMFSourceReader to read IMFSamples for that video?

Comment: Have you tried using the Source Resolver? First create IMFSoureResolver, then call it's method to create media source object. As shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you are able to play the media file in TopoEdit, then you have the necessary MF demuxers/decoders.

Comment: Yes I tried IMFSoureResolver and CreateObjectFromByteStream(). Still shows The Byte Stream Type of the Given URL is unsupported. If I use MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL() or CreateObjectFromURL() it returns E_ACCESSDENIED error.

Comment: This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says if MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE is returned Specify the MIME type by setting the MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE attribute on the byte stream. But it does not say how to set it and what values it will take.

Comment: Didn't done this my self. Looks like you have to query your IMFByteStream object for IMFAttributes (or acquire it some other way). Then call IMFAttributes::SetString() using that GUID as a key to set a mime-type. Not sure if it is available on Win RT. Here is a list of mime types: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/