# E_ACCESSDENIED Error with Video File open with IMFSourceReader or IMFSourceResolver

Tags: video, c++-cx, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to open video files using `IMFSourceReader->MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL()` or `IMFSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromURL()`. But both of them are returning E_ACCESSDENIED General Access denied error.

I am in windows 8.1 desktop and the video is in Pictures Library folder. I have the Capability for Pictures Library checked in `Package.appxmanifest page`. But still I am getting access denied error.

any idea how I can get rid of this problem?

Edit: I am passing the video URL with this format L"C:/Users/user.name/Pictures/video.mp4"
If I run the code in console application there is no error using this code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#creating_source_reader). If I run the same code in WinRT it does not work. CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); returns `cannot change thread mode after it is set` and source reader says access denied. Is the access denied error has something to do with threading?

Comment: If you are making a metro application, this will answer you question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ae1ac4cd-471e-4215-a421-338f3c01d9a6/how-can-use-mfcreatesourcereaderfromurl-to-access-video-file-in-metro?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment

Comment: I am trying to make WinRT library. Thanks for your direction. I came across your given link before and tried to use ByteStream. It led me to problems and I had to post a question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992455/using-imfsourcereader-to-open-a-video-file

Comment: That's why I am trying to avoid going through opening file with ByteStream with custom ByteStreamHandler. MSDN says to use MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL() and gives example of using it. But it gives me access denied error and nowhere in MSDN it provides solutions to this problem.

Comment: @Anton Angelov: I have just found an important thing and edited the question. If i run the code in console application there is no error.

Comment: Look here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/533dd802-e0ca-4d58-a56b-1f5e9c98ef41/how-to-use-winrt-api-from-my-clr-desktop-app Have you tried using RoInitialize instead of CoInitializeEx? And RoActivateInstance instead of CoCreateInstance?